# How to install Git on windows - where to download and which version

Tags: windows, git

I want to install git on windows.  my main interest is using it from command line rather than a gui.

Googling takes me to http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list but this has words like preview and beta -  gives me a cool feeling.  Where can I download it and which version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am using the msys based version of git on Windows. It's actually really well done. You get lots of niceties for free like bash tab completion, branch indication, gitk is hooked up, etc.

The fact that they are unwilling to call these releases "final" has never been an issue. I've never had any problems.

And btw, github sends you to that installer for git on Windows too. Which should give you a bit more confidence.

Answer (score 1):

`gitforwindows.org` and `git-scm.com` are both legit.

The [Download for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) page links to `git-for-windows.github.io`, which is now a redirect to https://gitforwindows.org/.